# Azure Function (Java) add attribute to CustomDimensions

Tags: java, azure-functions, telemetry

I am desperatly searching on how to add a new attribute to the custom dimensions collection in the request table of the log analytics in the context of a Java function.

[image]

I know in C# you can do it using Activity and ITelementryInitializer but for Java I can not get it to work.
Any hints are appreciated. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> `Azure Function (Java) add attribute to CustomDimensions`

In Java, we have the Span attributes concept for adding the optional (extra) fields to the App Insights Schema that populates with the `customDimensions` in the form of various tables such as `traces`, `exceptions`, `dependencies`.

For that, one of the dependencies is required which is `opentelemetry-api-1.jar`.

```java
AttributeKey newAttributeKey= AttributeKey.stringKey("resourcecustomDimension"); Span.current().setAttribute(newAttributeKey, "customDimValue");
```

This brings us the custom attributes for the custom dimensions that will be added to the Telemetry data.

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent#add-span-attributes) for more information on adding the attributes to the `customDimensions` and found the GitHub issue [13310](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/13310) regarding the user seeking for the Java Code on `ITelemetryInitializer` where the sample code on it provided by @*dhaval24* user.